# SELECT Value where date is the oldest in a sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I want to return a value from a sub query where the date is the oldest.

tablea

```
id  sub  bid
1   1    1
1   2    2
1   3    1
1   4    1
2   1    2
2   2    1
```

tableb

```
id value  date
1  red    01/01/2016
1  blue   05/01/2016
2  red    07/01/2016
2  green  03/01/2016
2  yellow 08/01/2016
```

Expected Output

```
id  sub  value
1   1    red
1   2    green
1   3    red
1   4    red
2   1    green
2   2    red
```

Current Code

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.sub,
       (SELECT b.value FROM tableb b WHERE b.date = MIN(b.date)) AS value
FROM tablea a
INNER JOIN tableb b ON a.bid = b.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the minimum per `id`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.sub, b.value
FROM tablea a INNER JOIN
     (SELECT b.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) as seqnum
      FROM tableb b
     ) b
     ON a.bid = b.id and b.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Not getting any errors but its been running for 15 minutes now, is this an efficient way to do this with lots of data

Comment: You must have a lot of data.  Indexes would help:  `tableb(id, date)`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using NOT EXISTS():

```
SELECT t.id,t.sub,s.value
FROM TableA t INNER JOIN TableB s ON(t.bid = s.id)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tableB f
                 WHERE f.id = s.id and f.date < s.date)
```

This basically do the join, and then filters all those who has a bigger date then the current value which keep you with all the latest dates.